# System.OutOfMemoryException using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to save hundreds of thousands of records using Entity framework. After saving few hundreds of thousands of records I get following error:

:System.OutOfMemoryException

My code

```
  foreach (BibContent objbibcontents in lstBibContent)
        {
            db.BibContents.AddObject(objbibcontents);
            c = c + 1;
            if (c == 1000)
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                c = 0;
            }
        }
```

I noticed after saving 1000 records my db is not overriding another 1000  records. it is adding them into my dbcontext.

I am creating a new instance after 1000 records but my db still has the previous object's data. See my code

```
   foreach (var objbibcontents in lstBibContent)
            {
                vibrantEntities db1 = new vibrantEntities(szConStr);
                lstBibCon.Add(objbibcontents);
                // db.BibContents.AddObject(objbibcontents);
                c = c + 1;
                if (c == 1000)
                {
                    foreach (BibContent bibobject in lstBibCon)
                    {
                        db1.BibContents.AddObject(bibobject);
                    }
                    lstBibCon.Clear();
                    db1.SaveChanges();
                    c = 0;
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 13):

How many objects are you going to save and how big is single object? DbContext holds references to all objects you added with `AddObject` call. Calling `SaveChanges` does not purge its internal data structures so if you call your code for 1M objects you will have 1M object in memory and they will be fully alive because their root object for GC will be the context instance which is still in scope of your running code.

If you want to avoid the memory issue you should use a new context instance for every 1000 records (or even every record). The only difference between running `SaveChanges` for 1000 records and for single record is the automatically involved transaction.

Comment: You would have to go and set each added object as detached. Creating a new context instance is much better way.

Answer (score 4):

I  search  on  Web  and  Finally  i  found  good  solution  for  my  problem.

[Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)